# Structural Question about Elements of $SO(2n)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups

Let $R_\theta$ denote the appropriate element of $SO(2)$, as is conventional.  Let $n$ be a positive integer, and consider $D = \text{diag}(R_{\theta_1}, \dots, R_{\theta_n}) \in SO(2n)$.  For simplicity, assume the $\theta_i$ are in $[0, 2\pi)$ and are distinct.

Question:  If there exists an orthonormal basis, $\beta$, of $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ such that
\begin{equation*}
     M_\beta(D) = g^{-1}Dg = \text{diag}(R_{\psi_1}, \dots, R_{\psi_n}),
\end{equation*}
where the $i^{th}$ column of $g$ is the $i^{th}$ vector of $\beta$, and $\psi_i \in [0, 2\pi)$, then is it true that $\left\{ \theta_i \right\} = \left\{ \psi_i \right\}$?

Many thanks!

Comment: Though user1551's answer is correct, if I changed "$\left\{ \theta_j \right\} = \left\{ \psi_j \right\}$" to "$\left\{ \theta_j \right\} \subset \left\{ \pm \psi_j \right\}$", then the statement would be true. This is because the eigenvalues of $D$ are $\exp(\pm i \theta_j)$ and similar matrices posses the same spectrum.  A stronger statement is true: There exists a permutation of n elements, $\sigma$, such that, for each $j = 1, \dots, n$, we have $\theta_j \in \left\{ \pm \psi_{\sigma(j)} \right\}$.

Comment: Minor correction: I should have written, at the end, "$\theta_j \in \left\{ \pm \psi_{\sigma(j)} \pmod{2\pi} \right\}$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $n=2$ and $g=g^{-1}=\pmatrix{0&I_2\\ I_2&0}$.